python import PyQt5 working in debug, not in executable
I'm slowly getting confused because I can't load a module from PyQt5. I create a script that starts a subprocess in which another script is executed. So that I only need one executable file, I load the script into the file with "pyinstaller --onefile --add-data=".\assets\scripts\script2.py". So that I have access to the modules from the first script, I pass the values ​​for "sys.path" as parameters to the second script. Unfortunately, this is not executed as expected, but gives me an error that the module cannot be found....
How my scripts are build:
script1.py
main script, converted to executable:
from assets.modules.module1 import Class1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Class1("arg1", "arg2")
    while True:
        # some code here...
        # foo
        # bar

assets.modules.module1
this module starts the subprocess:
import sys
from subprocess import Popen

# code
# foo
# bar
def resourcePath(resource: str) -> str:
    """
    Get the absolute path to a resource.
    Works for both development (debug) and PyInstaller (release).
    """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores the path in `_MEIPASS`
        basePath = sys._MEIPASS
    except AttributeError:
        # Access the path in development mode
        basePath = path.abspath(".")
    return path.join(basePath, resource).replace("\\", "/")


def doSomething(arg1, arg2):
    # to read the path when compiled to executable
    with open("path/to/sys_path.txt", "w") as file
        file.write(str(sys.path)) 

    proc = Popen([resourcePath("assets/executables/pythonw.exe"),
                  resourcePath("assets/scripts/script2.py"),
                  arg1,
                  arg2,
                 ] + sys.path
    # foo
    # bar
    # code

script2.py
script to be executed in subprocess, opens a window:
import sys

if len(sys.argv) > 3:
    sys.path = sys.argv[3:]

with open("sys_path.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(str(sys.path))

try:
    # ERROR here!
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QUrl
    from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
except Exception as e:
    with open("error.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write("e.msg:\n" + e.msg + "\n\n" + "e.path:\n" + e.path)
    raise e

"""
Exception has occurred: ImportError
DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified module was not found.
  File "Project\path\assets\modules\script2.py", line 16, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QUrl, QTimer
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: The specified module was not found.
"""

sys_path.txt
sys.path are both identical:
['C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI138122\\base_library.zip', 'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI138122\\lib-dynload', 'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI138122', 'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI138122\\setuptools\\_vendor']
['C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI138122\\base_library.zip', 'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI138122\\lib-dynload', 'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI138122', 'C:\\Users\\USER~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI138122\\setuptools\\_vendor']

error.txt
the error of importing PyQt5 Modules:
e.msg:
DLL load failed while importing QtCore: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.

e.path:
C:\Users\USER~1\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI254722\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd

script1.spec
the .spec for pyinstaller script1.spec:
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

# Import collect_all to gather all dependencies for PyQt5 modules
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import collect_all

# Collect data, binaries, and hidden imports for PyQt5 modules
datas, binaries, hiddenimports = collect_all('PyQt5.QtCore')
datas += collect_all('PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets')[0]
binaries += collect_all('PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets')[1]
hiddenimports += collect_all('PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets')[2]
datas += collect_all('PyQt5.QtWidgets')[0]
binaries += collect_all('PyQt5.QtWidgets')[1]
hiddenimports += collect_all('PyQt5.QtWidgets')[2]

a = Analysis(
    ['script1.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries= binaries + [('.\\assets\\executables\\*', 'assets/executables')],
    datas= datas + [('.\\assets\\modules\\*', 'assets/modules'),
                    ('.\\assets\\pictures\\*', 'assets/pictures'),
                    ('.\\assets\\sites\\*', 'assets/sites'),
                    ('.\\assets\\sounds\\*', 'assets/sounds') ],
    hiddenimports=hiddenimports,
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
    optimize=0,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='script1_executable',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=False,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)

what my filesystem looks like
path is inside the sys_path.txt, so it should work??:


Update:
Now my application works... But I had to copy the folder C:\Python312\Lib to my assets and also the C:\ProjectPath\venv\Lib\site-packages folder to the assets. Now my executable has an amazing size of 250MB -.-
I guess the problem were some dependend modules, either by PyQt5 or pythonw.exe itself.
Does anyone know what exactly I have to import (maybe with a --hidden-import) to get my application smaller?
Thank you very much,
Micha

I wasn't able to reproduce the error based on the code and information you provided.
But here are some steps that might help you debug the issue:

Make sure only the PyQt5 module is raising the error:

rather than copy everything over to your asset, try copy only site-packages/PyQt5 over, and see if that solves it


Just list out PyQt5 and the sub-modules you need, instead of using collect_all to collect everything:
a = Analysis(
    # ....
    hiddenimports=["PyQt5", "PyQt5.QtCore", "PyQt5.QtWidgets", "PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets"],
    # ....
)


UPX compressing (this step is only to reduce binary executable size)
Though you've already set upx=True in the EXE(...) part, but you still have to make sure that you've put upx.exe in your working directory, or specify --upx-dir=.\upx_exe\location\folder when running your spec through command-line, or else it won't do anything.



if step 1 & 2 still won't solve the issue, give --onedir a try.


You can still pack a --onedir result into a single setup.exe using stuff like Inno Setup


You are right, it is not ony the PyQt5 module raising the error:
I guess the problem is, that i call the pythonw.exe, which I just copied from "C:\Python312\pythonw.exe" into my assets directory. I guess it also needs some libraries to run? Or the PyQt5 module needs some standard libraries to run, which i have to import first? I copied now the directories for the modules out of "venv\Lib" and the directory "C:\Python312\Lib" into my assets, everything fine, no problem.. But if i just delete one of the tow directories and try to use --collect-all or --hidden-import (which i tried first) I fail

When I compile the Script2 to executable directly, then I have no problems. Comparing
